# Why most people use .json in nodejs projects?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, configuration

Im working with nodejs for backend. And im asking myself why should I use config.json, data.json etc. Why not to use js object and make deepFreeze to it? Whats the benefits of json?

Like:

```
const config = {
 serviceName: test,
 port: 4050,
};

const deepFreeze = obj => {
Object.keys(obj).forEach(prop => {
 if (typeof obj[prop] === 'object' && !Object.isFrozen(obj[prop])) 
  deepFreeze(obj[prop]);
});
 return Object.freeze(obj);
};
deepFreeze(config);
```

Comment: What's the benefit of using a JavaScript object and freezing it? To answer your question, JSON is pure text, so it's highly compatible. Works in browsers, Node, Python, you name it. It's a data structure store like YAML. JavaScript on the other hand, only works for JavaScript. Also, people *often* use JavaScript files for configs. The biggest example is webpack config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

json is a text format for representing arrays and objects easily.

The interest of json is that it is independent of a language.

You can read or write JSON from javascript, but also from other languages.

Moreover, during exchanges between a client and a server, it is easy to use it to transport data.